# jquery remove direct child element

Tags: jquery

Using jQuery, how can I remove an anchor tag in my html body which also consists of a wrapper div, and this wrapper div is above the anchor tag that I want to remove.

It is like

```
<body>
    <div id="wrapper"> 
        <a id="not_me" href="#">hi</a>
    </div> 

    <a id="remove_me" href="#">Remove Me</a>

</body>
```

If I use

```
$("body").find("a:first-child").remove();
```

it removes the first anchor tag in my wrapper div i.e. one with id "not_me", while I want "remove_me" to be removed.

Answer (score 51, accepted):

```
$("body").children("a:first").remove();
```

You use [`children()`<sup>*(docs)*</sup>](http://api.jquery.com/children/) because you only want to target direct children of `body`.

Then use `"a:first"` as the selector to target the first `<a>` element.

This is because with the [`first-child-selector`<sup>*(docs)*</sup>](http://api.jquery.com/first-child-selector/) you'll only get the `<a>` *if* it is the first child of its parent (which it isn't). But with the [`first-selector`<sup>*(docs)*</sup>](http://api.jquery.com/first-selector/) you get the first `<a>` that was matched.

Alternative would be to place it all in one selector:

```
$('body > a:first').remove();
```

Same as above, but uses the `>` [`child-selector`<sup>*(docs)*</sup>](http://api.jquery.com/child-selector/) instead of the [`children()`<sup>*(docs)*</sup>](http://api.jquery.com/children/) method.

Comment: aahhh! sup me one more time! I just love that.. :p)

Comment: @jAndy: There's a couple more for you. :o)

Answer (score 10):

You want to use `children()` to search on direct children only, and you can use `:first` or `eq(0)` to remove the first one:

```
$("body").children("a").eq(0).remove();
```

Answer (score 8):

why don't you try:

```
$("#remove_me").remove()
```

don't know if it's wrong, I'm still learning :P

Comment: That's correct, but I have a feeling OP just used the IDs for the sake of the example to show which `<a>` was targeted, and which wasn't. :o)

Comment: sorry but forgot to mention that the id ("remove_me" is e.g.) is generated dynamically so we can not use the method you suggested, anyways thanks for response